# Dictionary in Python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, request

I have question. I try to get info from function and pack result into dictionary like this:

```
import requests
class CommonUtils():
    def get_data_list(self, url, listType):
        c_list = requests.get(url)
        data = {"json": c_list.json(), "text": c_list.text}
        return data.get(listType)
```

I debugged function and I know, that **requests** retrieves info from passed **url**.

And when I try to return data, I get error with message: ***"AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'json'"***

What I do wrong?

Comment: Try to use `data[listType]` instead of `data.get(listType)`

Comment: @Alperen, thank you for answer. Tried it and got error with message "AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'json'" Irony of this situation is that current code works with Python 2.7 without any problem!

Comment: I found error. It was in another function. My apologies